# How can I create a msg(outlook) blob in azure storage using a workflow

Tags: azure, email, outlook, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create .msg file from shared mailbox using Azure Logic app. But logic app returns json , not able to create .msg file from it.

Comment: Hi Abi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately your question does not meet the standards of this site. Please start [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that will guide you into creating better questions. And read [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is MSG format a requirement? If you want just something you can open in Outlook, create an EML (MIME) file - Outlook will be happy to open it even EML won't be able to store all custom or Outlook specific properties. EML file format is text based, so it is easy to create in your code.

If you still need MSG format, your options are

1. Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi, Outlook must be installed for the MAPI system to be present) - see [StgOpenStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgopenstorage) / [StgCreateStorageEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgcreatestorageex) / [OpenIMsgOnIStg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/openimsgonistg) functions on MSDN.
2. Create MSG file explicitly in your code - its format is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec8), but it is as binary as it gets.
3. Third party libraries (such as [Aspose](https://docs.aspose.com/email/net/creating-and-saving-msg-files/)) - your mileage may vary.
4. Extended MAPI wrapper like Redemption (I am its author) - you can create an instance of the [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object and call `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile`, populate the [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object properties, and call `RDOMail.Save`.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, Here is one of the workarounds that worked for us. After mentioning the blob name along with its extension (.msg), we could able to get it to work.

Below is my Logic App Screenshot

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

In storage account

[image]

After downloading it to local

[image]